# Quicksort by length of String in Array

Tags: java, quicksort

I have strings scanned from the user. Next step is to sort array by the length of text, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, sometimes it's working.

```
public static void quickSort(String[] subtitles, int start, int end) {
    int i = start;
    int j = end;
    if (j - i >= 1) {
        String pivot = subtitles[i];
        while (j > 1) {
            while (subtitles[i].compareTo(pivot) <= 0 && i < end && j > i)
                i++;

            while (subtitles[j].compareTo(pivot) >= 0 && j > start && j >= i)
                j--;

            if (j > i)
                swap(subtitles, i, j);
        }

        swap(subtitles, start, j);
        quickSort(subtitles, start, j - 1);
        quickSort(subtitles, j + 1, end);
    } else
        return;
}

public static void swap(String[] a, int i, int j) {
    String tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int amountStrings = 3;
    String[] subtitles = new String[amountStrings];
    System.out.println("insert ");
    for (int i = 0; i < amountStrings; i++) {
        subtitles[i] = scan.next();
    }

    System.out.println("--------");

    quickSort(subtitles, 0, subtitles.length - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < subtitles.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(subtitles[i] + " ");
    }
```

Incorrect:

In:
asdzxc asd zxc

Out:
asd asdzxc zxc

Correct:

In: 
sdf sdfsfwer s
Out:

s sdf sdfsfwer

Comment: What happened when you tried debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I reviewed your code and made two new methods. One sorts the array alphabetically and one sorts by counting the number of letters in each word of the array. It is up to you what methods fits you well. 
Tested and working.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Subtitles {

    public static void sortAlfabetical(String x[]) {
        int j;
        boolean found = true; // will determine when the sort is finished
        String temp;

        while (found) {
            found = false;
            for (j = 0; j < x.length - 1; j++) {
                if (x[j].compareToIgnoreCase(x[j + 1]) > 0) { // ascending sort
                    temp = x[j];
                    x[j] = x[j + 1]; // swap
                    x[j + 1] = temp;
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
        }
    }



    public static void compare(String[] arrayOne) {

        Arrays.sort(arrayOne, new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.length() - o2.length();
            }
        });

        for (String s : arrayOne) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }

    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amountStrings = 3;
        String[] subtitles = new String[amountStrings];
        System.out.println("insert ");
        for (int i = 0; i < amountStrings; i++) {
            subtitles[i] = scan.next();
        }

        System.out.println("--------");


        System.out.print("Sorting alphabetical: ");
        sortAlfabetical(subtitles);
        System.out.println();


        System.out.println("===========================");
        System.out.print("Sorting by word length: ");
        compare(subtitles);


    }
}
```

Comment: ok if i write cars, elephant, boy its working, but when I'm change to elephant, boy, cars it's not working